# Convert HTML to SVG - Flying Saucer Java

Tags: java, pdf, svg, flying-saucer

I've been trying to use Flying Saucer to take HTML content and render it to a SVG. I've easily achieved it when I want a JPEG or PNG, but SVG's seem to a bit more complicated and I've been struggling to figure out the process a bit. (Mainly because I'm a Java noob as it were).

I've been trying to follow [this](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983589) but it looks like the examples don't quite work, and trying to follow the demos they have bundled I was struggling with a bit as well, plus most examples try and get a browser involved which I don't really care about. All I want is to take the HTML and convert it to a SVG so I can use it as resource in a PDF. This is what I have PNG conversion:

```
BufferedImage buff = null;
buff = Graphics2DRenderer.renderToImage("content.html", 1000, 1000);

File outputfile = new File("test.png");
ImageIO.write(buff, "PNG", outputfile);
```